# How do I perfect my gemology?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

I've noticed that you need twelve designs to get the acheivement "perfect gemology". But there are only five different kinds of gems with two designs each, so that gives 10 designs to find.

I've teached the jeweler a (lvl 60) ring plan, but that didn't count.

So how do I get myself these last two designs? What am I missing?

Comment: There are plans for rings and amulets to find.

Comment: I believe there's 3 designs per gem. Flawless Imperial, Royal and Flawless Royal. That would be 15 to find.

Comment: @Katustrawfic According to the website, the Flawless Imperial gems are learned when the Jeweler reaches level 12. http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/recipe/flawless-imperial-amethyst

Comment: @Assylum I *did* find a plan for a ring, and using that did *not* increase the count, as written in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems I was mistaken. Jewels crafting pages *do* count, it's just the achievement pages who update with a delay.

I just got the achievement by learning an amulet recipe.

The recipes learned counts over hardcore jeweler and normal jeweler together. So having 10 recipies unlocked in normal and two in hardcore will result in getting the achievement.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this achievement can be unlocked anymore, if you are level 70 and didn't teach the Jeweler any designs before Reaper of Souls.

According to the [Diablo 3 Game Guide](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/progression/#level=12), when the Jeweler is level 12 there are 11 designs that he can learn - 10 for Royal and Flawless Royal gems of each type, and the level 70 Hellfire Ring.

I'm not positive, but I think that all of the gems available at level 60 (up through Marquise) are unlocked for all players now, so those designs don't drop and won't count.

Comment: You might still be able to get the plan drops before you hit lvl 60, but it's probably essentially impossible to get them all because you'd likely hit 60 well before finding them all.

Comment: As we were leveling to 70, my wife got one of the other plans as a drop (shoulders or bracers, I think). So it's still possible for them to drop past 60.

Comment: As has been stated in the question and the other answer, amulet/ring plans do not contribute towards the achievement.

Comment: @Doc When I first read the question I wasn't sure if that is what was referred to or not. I removed that portion of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To get *Perfect Gemology* achievement you should teach your [*Jeweler*](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/) all 12 gem designs:

> - [*Flawless Star Amethyst*](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/recipe/flawless-star-amethyst)
> - [*Flawless Star Ruby*](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/recipe/flawless-star-ruby)
> - [*Flawless Star Topaz*](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/recipe/flawless-star-topaz)
> - [*Flawless Star Emerald*](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/recipe/flawless-star-emerald)
> - [*Perfect Star Amethyst*](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/recipe/perfect-star-amethyst)
> - [*Perfect Star Ruby*](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/recipe/perfect-star-ruby)
> - [*Perfect Star Topaz*](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/recipe/perfect-star-topaz)
> - [*Perfect Star Emerald*](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/recipe/perfect-star-emerald)
> - [*Radiant Star Amethyst*](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/recipe/radiant-star-amethyst)
> - [*Radiant Star Ruby*](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/recipe/radiant-star-ruby)
> - [*Radiant Star Topaz*](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/recipe/radiant-star-topaz)
> - [*Radiant Star Emerald*](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/recipe/radiant-star-emerald)

As far as I know, designs for rings and/or amulets do not count towards this achievement

Comment: I don't think these are designs anymore, I can make all of these without ever having found one of these designs. They are all learned by leveling the jeweler.

Comment: I think this is out-of-date info, from before 2.0.